Async Request in ESB 12c
Hi I'm working with ESB 12c, I need to make an asynchronous request(without using jms/queue)
Is it possible to make an asynchronous request to PROXY SERVICE or BS?
My goal is for the request to be sent without waiting for an answer, which means that the pipeline will continue to the next stage no matter what happened with the request I sent.
I work directly on the console (SERVICE BUS)
I would appreciate your help, thanks.
I thought about publish action,
but I don't know what exactly needs to be defined, because I read several posts with different opinions on this topic
